# Overriding the paint() method in JButton

Tags: java, swing, paint, jbutton, look-and-feel

I have a class that extends JButton because the custom look and feel I'm using ignores the isOpaque() call. What I mean is, the background of the button is rendered even though I have called setOpaque (false) on it and all parent panels. I have confirmed that this is an issue with the LAF from the companies design people so there is nothing I can do but extend the class. 
So my question is, how can I implement the paint() method to not render the background and just the button icon?
Cheers

SOLVED: The answer I was after in case anyone is interested was to use `button.setContentAreaFilled(false);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Painting is done by three methods: paintComponent, paintBorder, and paintChildren.  They're called in that order and it's the first that paints the component's background.  If you overload that one and leave the other two, you should be fine.

Comment: I have tried overriding the paintComponent(final Graphics g) call which then led me to extend the ComponentUI class to override the update(final Graphics g, final JComponent c) method. From here, I am able to prevent a background color being drawn, I am unable however to get the original icon to draw by calling c.repaint(); Could you perhaps advise on a solution/course of action?